# I'm creating a new scratch org - will it be based on Summer '19 (production org edition) or Spring '19 (sandbox edition)?

Tags: scratch-org, editions

I can't find the answer to this anywhere quickly -  what controls the edition?  Production is on Summer '19 while all previous scratch orgs are on the Spring '19.  If I create a new scratch org now after the GA release , will that scratch org have Summer '19 functions?

Edit:  tested this.  It's summer '19.  So there you have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once your production org is on summer 19 and if it has the devhub enabled all the new scratch orgs will be on summer 19 only .

Note that from next release (when winter 20) devhub will allow to create orgs in Salesforce pre release version as well .